# scanner input undefined for String? JAVA

Tags: java

This program prompts the store owner for the amount of cash at the beginning and end of the day, and the name of the file. It should check whether the actual amount of cash at the end of the day equals the expected value.

I have a txt file where each line contains three items: The invoice number, the cash amount, and the letter P if the amount was paid or R if it was received. Items are separated by spaces.

I am having trouble with this piece in my code

```
while (filename.hasNext()) {
    invoice.add(filename.nextInt());
    cash.add(filename.nextDouble());
    PR.add(filename.next());
}
```

It is a syntax error saying I cannot use `.nextInt() .nextDouble() .next() hasNext()`

Here is the full source code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Code for P11.11.  This program takes in a list of baby names and outputs a list of boys and
 * girls names.
 *
 * @Michael Goedken
 */
public class BalanceTransactions {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // The following lines ask the user to enter the file name and the balances at the beginning and the end
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the file name for input: ");
        String filename = in.next();

        System.out.print("Please enter the cash amount at the start: ");
        double start = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Please enter the cash amount at the end: ");
        double end = in.nextDouble();

        ArrayList<Integer> invoice = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Double> cash = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<String> PR = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (filename.hasNext()) {
            invoice.add(filename.nextInt());
            cash.add(filename.nextDouble());
            PR.add(filename.next());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < invoice.size(); i++) {
            if (PR.get(i).equals("P")) {
                start -= cash.get(i);
            }
            if (PR.get(i).equals("R")) {
                start += cash.get(i);
            }
        }

        if (start == end || (double) Math.round(start * 1000000000) / 1000000000 == end) {
            System.out.println("There is the correct amount in the register.");

        } else {
            Double difference = ((double) Math.round(start * 100000) / 100000) - end;

            System.out.println("You are off by: " + difference);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I added a new scanner now I get this error

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner("/Users/MichaelGoedken/Desktop/transactions.txt");

      while (fileScanner.hasNext()) 
      {
          invoice.add(fileScanner.nextInt());
          cash.add(fileScanner.nextDouble());
          PR.add(fileScanner.next());
      }
```

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at BalanceTransactions.main(BalanceTransactions.java:34)
```

Comment: What do you think `filename.nextInt()` should do? Why do you think so?

Comment: Because ``filename`` is a ``String`` variable. These methods are provided by a ``Scanner`` instance, in your code that variable is called ``in``.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was hoping it would fill that array list with the integers in the text file

Comment: `filename` is a string, so I should change all them to `in`?

Comment: Create another Scanner which will read from file provided by `in.next()` (or maybe `in.nextLine()` if you want to let user provide file or path which could contain spaces). So you need something like `Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(pathToFile);` and use it like `fileScanner.nextInt()`.

Comment: @Pshemo I tried to implement what you said is this how you pictured it? I added the edit to main post

Comment: It contains name of file. You can use it while constructing Scanner. About `InputMismatchException` it means your scanner attempted to read something which didn't match expected type, for instance you had `abc` but tried to read it via `nextInt()`. What exactly went wrong is hard to tell without knowing content of file. Try using debugger or simply print what you read in loop like `int inv = nextIn();//invoice` `System.out.println(inv);` `invoice.add(inv);` (do same for rest of values in loop).

Comment: The .txt file is very simple it is 4 lines as follows: 10001 56.67 P
10002 23.67 R
10003 99.50 R
10004 10.95 P

Comment: @Pshemo The first number is an int and the second a double I don't understand how it is a mismatch

Comment: Which line is 34?

Comment: @Pshemo `invoice.add(fileScanner.nextInt());` line 34

Comment: Just a guess, but could file you are reading be encoded using encoding with BOM (Byte Order Mark which is invisible character placed at start of the file)? If yes, try to change its encoding to something without it (in Notepad++ you can use Encoding-> Convert to UTF-8)

Comment: Take a look at posted answer. I gave you incorrect example in `new Scanner(pathToFile)`, it should be `new Scanner(new File(pathToFile))`. My incorrect example would treat `pathToFile` as raw data, not as information where to look for data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to scan a file, try to use this constructor:

```
/**
 * Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned
 * from the specified file. Bytes from the file are converted into
 * characters using the specified charset.
 *
 * @param  source A file to be scanned
 * @throws FileNotFoundException if source is not found
 */
public Scanner(File source) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this((ReadableByteChannel)(new FileInputStream(source).getChannel()));
}
```

Right now you are using this constructor, it doesn't make any sense, because you pass as a parameter String:

```
public Scanner(String source) {
    this(new StringReader(source), WHITESPACE_PATTERN);
}
```

Comment: What do I put as the parameters for the class `Scanner`? You just put file source and I tried adding the path there but that doesn't look right

Comment: @MikeGoedken What do you mean by "doesn't look right"? Also don't just describe your code, show it to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: `public Scanner (?) throws FileNotFoundException` for this line what do I add to the parameters of the class?

Comment: In your case, it could be something like this: Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/MichaelGoedken/Desktop/transactions.txt"));

Comment: It works! :):) thank you!